# Errors start to appear after install Java in Visual Studio for Salesforce DX

Tags: salesforcedx

Everything was working fine untill I link the Java JDK 11 to visual code. After that errors appear on my Apex classes like the screenshot below. Anyone know how to fix it ? is there any configuration I have to setup?
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Can you share your user/workspace settings and how you set the Salesforce Java home property?  Ensure your new settings path is hitting the right endpoint / Java JDK properly.  Some good examples are here - [Java Setup](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/getting-started/java-setup/)